# Defining a custom "chainable" ActiveRelation method like `order` and `limit`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails has these lovely [chainable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) methods. How do I add my own? I thought of defining a class method in the model from which I want to invoke my custom method, but this would only work at the beginning of a "chain":

```
class << self
  def order_by_specialness
    order(:specialness)
  end
end
```

I suspect I would need to extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` somehow, as this is what's returned by the each of the chainable query methods. But from there, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `scope`:

```
scope :order_by_specialness, order(:specialness)
```

Call with:

```
User.order_by_specialness.first
```

Although using `order_by_specialness` doesn't really save you any time. You should use something just like `special`:

```
User.special.first
```

Comment: Named scopes are 'dead';  http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Comment: To expand on @Garrett, the Railway author who suggests not using scopes filed a bug with the rails team, which they fixed, making his view that one should not use scopes moot.  https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994-ruby-on-rails/tickets/4142-arel-methods-in-scope-cause-issues-with-non-existent-tables